# encoding - decoding, accents

Tags: objective-c

I'm extracting data from my database using php and JSON:

```
$output[]=array("userJoomla" => "2749", "userID" => $e['mobileUserID'], "userName" =>  utf8_encode($e['mobileUserName']));
```

I use utf8_encode because of written accents and spanish letter ñ

In my objective-c code:

```
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But, when I print it i get:

"Roc\u00edo" instead of "Rocío"

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without encoding the username value ? If your database is configure to uses utf8, the value should already be encoding like this. So if you encode a utf8 string in utf8 the result should looks like pretty bad

Comment: I did, but if I do this, the userName value is null, why is this happenning?

Comment: That's stange... Did you try to call your webservice with a web browser ? What's the result ?